# Вводные слова с однородными членами

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильный вариант постановки знаков препинания.
А. *По сути, и дома, и на улице холодно.*
Б. *По сути и дома, и на улице холодно.*

Answer (score 1):

Если сочетание ["по сути"](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_605) употреблено в качестве вводного, то после него я бы запятую поставила.
Возможно, вы ориентируетесь вот на это правило Розенталя:

> Вводное слово (сочетание) не отделяется знаком препинания от обособленного оборота, если находится в самом начале или в самом конце предложения: ***По-видимому опасаясь снежных заносов,** руководитель группы отменил восхождение на вершину горы; Оставьте вы эти новые доводы, **неубедительные и надуманные конечно.***

В конечном предложении вводное слово относится только к последним однородным членам, а в нашем предложении — ко всем.

**По сути, и дома, и на улице холодно.**
*Пока же под угрозой не только заборы, но, **по сути, и дома, и** любые **хозпостройки**, расположенные на береговой полосе* (из статьи).

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

Я, **конечно, и ел, и пил, и занимался** разными вещами ― например, ходил в университет, ― но не думаю, чтобы это было кому-нибудь интересно (Вера Белоусова. Второй выстрел).

**По-видимому, и в автобиографии, и в** архивной **статье** речь идет об одном и том же исследовании (М. А. Степанова. Интеллектуальная собственность на «интеллектуальную одаренность» (2003) // «Вопросы психологии», 23.12.2003).

**Казалось, и трава, и дерёвья** принюхиваются, вздыхают: соскучились по грибам (Виталий Коржиков. Подарок // «Мурзилка», 2003).

[Вводные слова и словосочетания](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122) (п. 4)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140000/discussion-on-answer-by-------).

Comment: Ориентируются по каким-то правилам, а не на какие-то правила.

Comment: Чего у вас "на"?