# Ориентироваться — НА правила или ПО правилам?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

Вопрос возник отсюда: [Вводные слова с однородными членами](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472384/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8/472390?noredirect=1#comment499774_472390).

Из моего ответа: *Возможно, вы **ориентируетесь** вот **на это правило** Розенталя...*

Из комментариев:
*Ориентируются по каким-то правилам, а не на какие-то правила.

Чего у вас "на"?*

Обсудим — как же правильно?

Comment: Нет в словарях подходящего значения.

Comment: Правила — это своего рода инструкция. Вы же не скажете "*ориентироваться на инструкцию*"?

Comment: Чего ж не скажу? Очень даже скажу: *Бухгалтерский учет затрат на осуществление добычи нефти производится в соответствии с учетной политикой, разработанной нефтедобывающей организацией самостоятельно, при формировании которой можно **ориентироваться на Инструкцию** по планированию, учету и калькулированию себестоимости добычи нефти и газа, утвержденную 01.11.1994 г. Министерством топлива и энергетики России* (Учет в нефтегазодобывающей отрасли 2-е изд. Учебник и практикум для вузов).

Comment: @oleedd Дополнительно: ориентироваться на инструкцию (https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E%22&ei=WO5bY--5POqSrgT1w6HQCw&start=40&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjvxZWNmIP7AhVqiYsKHfVhCLo4FBDy0wN6BAgBEA0&biw=1366&bih=657&dpr=1).

Comment: @oleedd Дополнительно: ориентироваться на закон. *Декарт сказал так: законы и установления не предшествуют полноте бытия или полноте проявления воли, так как последняя выступает в виде закона не потому, что мы **ориентировались на закон**, а потому что так ― сделали, так проявилась полнота воли ― и это стало законом. А Шестов на это возражал: и что это за свобода, которая **ориентируется на законы**!* (Мераб Мамардашвили. Введение в философию (1986)).

Comment: Тогда когда какой предлог использовать, по-вашему?

Comment: Предлог "по": 1. Если вы ориентируетесь по каким-то объектам, приборам, растениям, жилищам животных и т. п., значит, вы определяете с их помощью, где вы находитесь и куда вам нужно двигаться. *Ориентироваться по компасу, по карте, по солнцу, по луне, по звёздам. | Ориентироваться на маяк. | В лесу можно ориентироваться по пням, муравейникам, цветам*. Кстати, можно ориентироваться и **по** маяку. *Японские миноносцы **ориентировались по маяку** на Золотой горе и огням эскадры* (Н. П. Зырянов. Колчак).

Comment: Не то имею в виду. Что же вы элементарные вещи говорите... Когда "по инструкции", а когда "на инструкцию" и т.п.?

Comment: Если у меня есть инструкция "Как пробраться сквозь дремучий лес", то я в дебрях ориентируюсь (выбираю путь, направление движения) по инструкции.

Comment: Вот мне так с любой инструкцией хочется. Если "ориентироваться" означает "действовать", то "по". С "на" другое получается.

Answer (score 2):

Не вижу ничего странного и неправильного в сочетании "ориентироваться **на** правило".

> [**ОРИЕНТИРОВАТЬСЯ**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F&all=x) <...> **3.** *на кого-что*. Определить - определять направление своей деятельности, линию своего поведения в зависимости от кого-, чего-л., рассчитывая на кого-, что-л. *О. на массового читателя. О. на европейские страны. О. на мировые стандарты.*

[*Грамота.ру*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%9E%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0&start=15) в своих ответах часто использует предлог ***на**: ориентироваться на статью, на словарь, на правило, на написание, на форму, на название, на вариант, на практику*... Думаю, что если бы такое управление было неверным, то на это давно бы обратили внимание.

**Дополнение** после комментариев oleedd'a

Пусть примеры из словаря не подходят к нашему случаю, но я понимаю формулировку значения так (в широком смысле): человек определяется со своей точкой зрения по поводу чего-то, ориентируясь на правила, рассчитывая на них, рассчитывая на то, что они помогли/помогают/помогут в правильном выборе направления мысли, письма и т. д.

А сочетание "ориентироваться **по** правилам" звучит так, как будто кто-то "правильно ориентируется" или, может, хорошо разбирается в этих самых правилах (но тогда нужно заменить на предлог ***в***).

P. S. Напишем "следовать правилам", "руководствоваться правилами" – и будет всем щастье! :)

Comment: Нет, здесь совсем другие примеры. В них нельзя использовать "по". У нас первое значение, а не третье.

Comment: Когда единственное, то лучше звучит. А вопрос о множественном. И существительное тоже играет роль. То есть и стилистику надо рассматривать.

Comment: @oleedd Читайте внимательно словарную статью (всё предельно чётко написано), даже если в примерах невозможно использовать ***по*** (только зачем?). А вот в ответах Грамоты можно и заменить, но привычнее звучит ***на*** (да и не просто звучит, а является нормой). Я высказал своё мнение, в комментариях участвовать больше не буду. Дайте свой ответ. // И да, считаю, что здесь именно 3-е значение. А вопрос о единственном числе.

Comment: В этом пункте значение — *делать так (менять свою деятельность), чтобы оно подходило читателям / европейским странам / под мировые стандарты*. А направление своей деятельности мы не меняем, когда действуем по правилам. В словаре Ушакова это значение описано так: Принять (принимать) ту или иную форму деятельности в зависимости от той или иной цели, **в расчете на кого-что-нибудь**. *Ориентироваться на рабочую аудиторию. Ориентироваться на массового читателя.* Вопрос о множественном. Прочитайте шапку.

Comment: @oleedd  Мы не меняем направление деятельности, а определяем его в зависимости от правила/правил, ориентируясь на него/них. Я ориентировался **на** изначальное предложение Риммы, где написано в ед. числе. Это уже вы в комментариях задали множественное, но это не имеет значения. Ох и приставучий вы :)) Мне добавить на сегодня нечего.

Comment: Это не направление деятельности. Направление — это нечто масштабное, например когда касается производства литературы (*ориентироваться на читателя*). В нашем же случае направление деятельности не меняется — писать грамотно. Не ставить запятую — это другое направление деятельности? Нет, этот пункт о другом, "в расчете на кого-что-нибудь" тому в подтверждение. Множественное использовал, потому что с ним звучит гораздо хуже. *Мне добавить на сегодня нечего* — моя задача как раз в том, чтобы вам нечего было добавить, тогда победа будет за мной :) А как не приставать, если дело касается меня лично?

Comment: Стоп, ну так там "**рассчитывая на кого-, что-либо**": *рассчитывая на читателя / европейские страны / аудиторию*. Это же деепричастие, то есть второе действие, уже не просто оборот с предлогом. Жаль, что сразу не заметил, не надо было бы спорить.

Comment: @oleedd  Опять по тому же месту. Я же написал: "не меняем, а **определяем**". И вы смешали в одну кучу саму формулировку значения и примеры. Здесь не "ориентироваться, рассчитывая на читателя". Деепричастие относится к "определить/определять". Я понимаю это так: кто-то определяется со своей точкой зрения по поводу чего-то, ориентируясь на правила, **рассчитывая** на них, **рассчитывая** на то, что они помогли/помогают/помогут в правильном выборе направления мысли, письма и пр. и пр. До  завтра!

Comment: Вы неправильно понимаете: *определять направление своей деятельности, рассчитывая на читателя*. У вас "рассчитывая" означает "надеясь", а в словарях буквальное значение (не *надеясь на читателя*). *А сочетание "ориентироваться по правилам" звучит так, как будто кто-то "правильно ориентируется" или, может, хорошо разбирается в этих самых правилах* — не звучит, переключитесь на другое значение: "*ориентироваться по правилам*" сопоставимо с "*ориентироваться по звёздам"*.

Answer (score 1):

Мне *кажется*, что подходящее значение имеется в толковом словаре Дмитриева:
[ориентироваться](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dmitriev/3176/%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F)
6. Если вы ориентируетесь на какие-либо характеристики или составляющие при оценке какой-то вещи, явления и т. п., значит, вы руководствуетесь этими характеристиками, составляющими при принятии решения относительно этой вещи, явления и т. п.
*Просматривая газету, читатель обычно ориентируется на название статьи. | Покупая плиту, домашняя хозяйка ориентируется на то, можно ли её быстро и дёшево отремонтировать.*

Попробуем "видоизмениться".
Если я ориентируюсь на правила при оценке пунктуации, значит, я руководствуюсь этими правилами при принятии решения относительно пунктуации.
Расставляя знаки препинания, я ориентируюсь на то, что написано в правилах (= на правила).

*Я вечно проявлял «не ту» инициативу, не был в комсомоле и не вел общественную работу, не занимался спортом, почти не танцевал и грустил на вечеринках; **не ориентировался на стандарты** и официальных героев, подвергался упрекам в «отрыве от коллектива» при всей общительности и активности моей природы* (Е. М. Мелетинский. Моя война).

*Хочется, чтобы будущий молодой специалист твердо **ориентировался на** основной **принцип**: быстро развивать химию ― это значит сегодня не только быстрее строить заводы* (Интервью с министром Л. А. Костандовым // «Химия и жизнь», 1965).

Comment: Это уже ближе, но не совсем то. Мы не оцениваем пунктуацию, у нас её нет изначально. А может, наше значение не совсем легальное, и поэтому его нет в базовых словарях? *не ориентировался на стандарты* — то третье значение (там тоже пример про стандарты). Как мне кажется: если копируем что-то, то "на" (*Ориентироваться на то, как написано в орфографическом словаре*); если действуем по "путеводителю" (правилам), то "по". В первом случае конкретный ответ, а во втором лишь гайд, по которому надо ориентироваться (то есть ещё надо мыслить).